# Understanding Factories and should I use them?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factories

I have never used Factories before for the simple reason, I don't understand when I need them. I have been working on a little game in my spare time, and I decided to implement FMOD for the sound. I looked at a wrapper designed for OpenAL(different sound setup) and it looked something like...

SoundObject*
SoundObjectManager*
SoundObjectFactory*

The SoundObject was basically the instance of each sound object. The SoundObjectManager just manages all of these objects. This is straight forward enough and makes plenty of sense, but I don't get what the factory is doing or what it is used. I have been reading up on Factorys but still don't really get them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of Factory as a "virtual constructor".  It lets you construct objects with a common compile time type but different runtime types.  You can switch behavior simply by telling the Factory to create an instance of a different runtime type.

Comment: So for something like this it really isn't needed? Considering I will always just be using instances of SoundObject* and just a singleton of the manager.

Comment: If you don't have different SoundObject subtypes, I'd say "no".

Comment: Not really, The intent in employing the pattern is to insulate the creation of objects from their usage. This allows for new derived types to be introduced with no change to the code that uses the base class. You probably have subtypes of SoundObject, but you just don't know it, the Factory insulates you from those implementation details

Comment: Here is the code from the project I was looking at (its pretty simple and small)

http://www.ampaste.net/m6055751b

He is returning a function in createInstanceImpl that has a return value of OgreOggISound* (which is an instance of the sound) but the return type for the function is MovableObject* so how exactly does that work? Is it just casting it to a MovableObject?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Factories are used when the implementation needs to be parametrized. FMOD is cross platform, it needs to decide what concrete implementation to give you for your platform. That is what the Factory is doing. There are two main Patterns [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetical situation:  I'm writing a sound library that I want to run on multiple platforms.  I'll try to make as much of the code as possible be platform independent, but certainly some of it will need to change for Windows versus OSX versus Linux.

So I write all these different implementations, but I don't want the end user to have to make *their* program depend on Linux or Windows or whatever.  I also don't want to maintain 4 different interfaces to my API.  (Note these are just some of the reasons you might create a factory -- there are certainly other situations).

So I define this nice generic `SoundObject` base class that defines all the methods the client gets to use.  Then I make my `LinuxSoundObject`, `WindowsSoundObject`, and 5 others derive from `SoundObject`.  But I'm going to hide all these concrete implementations from the user and only provide them with a `SoundObject`.  Instead, you have to call my `SoundObjectFactory` to grab what appears to you to be a plain old `SoundObject`, but really I've chosen the correct runtime type for you and instantiated it myself.

2 years later, a new OS comes about and displaces Windows.  Instead of forcing you to rewrite your software, I just update my library to support the new platform and you never see a change to the interface.

This is all pretty contrived, but hopefully you get the idea.

Factories isolate consumers of an interface from what runtime type (i.e. implementation) is really being used.

Comment: That make perfect sense, you should look into writing c++ for dummies books lol. As far as that link goes though I posted in the comment above, im still not exactly sure what hes doing, but it LOOKS like hes using the factory to turn it into a MovableObject, but I don't really get that.

Since this is just a learning project im going to go without one for now I suppose and I will know when I need to use one in the future.

Comment: This isn't C++ specific, it is a general design pattern for all OO languages ( and some non-OO )

Answer (score 0):

Factories can be used to implement inversion of control, and to separate instantiation code (the 'new's) from the logic of your components. This is helpful when you're writing unit tests since you may not want tested objects to create a bunch of other objects.